# Efficient way to apply a custom counting function on a large dataframe with dplyr or apply

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a fairly large dataframe (536  x 46000), and I would like to calculate the frequency of a minor element per each column. The example data snippet is here:

```
require(dplyr)

m1 <- c(0:2,NA,0:2,NA)
m2 <- c(NA, NA, 0:2,NA, 0, 2)
m3 <- c(0,1,1,1,2,0,NA,2)
g1 <- seq(1:20)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(g1,m1,m2,m3))
dat$g1 <- as.factor(dat$g1)
dat

 g1  m1  m2  m3
 1   0   NA  0
 2   1   NA  1
 3   2   0   1
 .   .   .   .
 .   .   .   .
```

I wrote a function to spit out the frequency of minor element. The function simply counts the occurrence of each element and divides the minor element by the sum of all elements except NA:

```
 maf.fun <- function(x) { 
    m0 <- length(which(x == 0)) 
    m1 <- length(which(x == 1))
    m2 <- length(which(x == 2))
    MAF <- min(m0,m1,m2)/sum(m0,m1,m2)
    MAF 
    }
```

Then used the `summarize_each` from `dplyr` package to get the frequency of the minor element by:

```
 MAF <- summarise_each(dat[,-1], funs(maf.fun))
```

It outputs:

```
  m1          m2        m3
  0.3333333   0.2       0.2857143
```

Now, this is all quick and nice when the dataset is small, however, the code goes painfully slow with the huge data frames (several thousand columns).

Is there any efficient way to do such calculations in an efficient way ?

Comment: Not sure it will speed it up a lot, but try using `m2 <- sum(x == 2)` for example instead.

Comment: @lmo, you might want to include `na.rm = T`

Comment: @wheatSingh, as per your code, `m2` and `m3` are `0.25` and `0.22`

Comment: The numbers might be incorrect in the example. `sum(x==2, na.rm=T)` is slightly more efficient than `length(which(x==2))`. Your earlier comment helped.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
fnc = function(x) min(table(x))/sum(!is.na(x))

dat %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(fnc), -g1)
```

However, this turns out to be quite a bit slower than `maf.fun` on your sample data. On the other hand, `maf.fun` isn't flexible in case the data can take many unique values (instead of just 0, 1, and 2), and could require a lot of typing to handle columns with more than a few unique values. So here's a function that will handle vectors with any number of unique values. This function runs almost as fast as `maf.fun`, but will work regardless of the number of unique values:

```
maf.fun2 = function(vec) {
  min(sapply(na.omit(unique(vec)), function(j) sum(vec==j, na.rm=TRUE)))/sum(!is.na(vec))
}

dat %>% summarise_each(funs(maf.fun2), -g1)
```

The base R equivalent would be:

```
sapply(dat[, -1], maf.fun2)
```

Here are some timings on a larger data frame. Note that base `sapply` is faster than `dplyr` `summarise_each`, and that with a larger data frame, there's not much difference between `fnc`, `maf.fun`, and `maf.fun2`:

536 rows x 1,000 columns; 3 possible column values, plus `NA`:

```
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(g1=1:536, replicate(1000, sample(c(0:2,NA), 536, replace=TRUE)))
```

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>             expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval  cld
>    dplyr_maf.fun 0.48 0.49 0.50   0.50 0.52 0.53     5  b  
>        dplyr_fnc 0.80 0.82 0.84   0.84 0.86 0.86     5    d
>   dplyr_maf.fun2 0.56 0.57 0.59   0.60 0.60 0.62     5   c 
>  sapply_maf.fun2 0.10 0.10 0.11   0.11 0.11 0.12     5 a
> ```

536 rows x 1,000 columns; 100 possible column values, plus `NA`:

```
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(g1=1:536, replicate(1000, sample(c(1:100,NA), 536, replace=TRUE)))
```

> ```
> Unit: seconds
>             expr  min   lq mean median   uq  max neval cld
>        dplyr_fnc 0.90 0.91 0.92   0.92 0.92 0.93     5  b 
>   dplyr_maf.fun2 0.99 1.02 1.05   1.03 1.09 1.11     5   c
>  sapply_maf.fun2 0.52 0.54 0.56   0.56 0.57 0.62     5 a
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to my comment, here is an attempt to speed up your calculation using `table`:

```
maf.fun <- function(x) { 
  myTable <- table(x)
  myTable <- myTable[names(myTable) %in% c("0", "1", "2")]

  min(myTable) / sum(myTable)
}
```

Comment: you missed `sum`. `min(myTable) / sum(myTable)`

Answer (score 1):

The major factor is the function you use to apply on each column, rather than the custom function itself. Here are some benchmarks:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
dat1 <- as.data.table(dat)
cols <- colnames(dat1)[2:length(dat1)]


# wheatSingh
maf.fun1 <- function(x) { 
    m0 <- length(which(x == 0)) 
    m1 <- length(which(x == 1))
    m2 <- length(which(x == 2))
    MAF <- min(m0,m1,m2)/sum(m0,m1,m2)
    MAF 
}


# lmo1
maf.fun2 <- function(x) { 
    m0 <- sum(x == 0, na.rm = T) 
    m1 <- sum(x == 1, na.rm = T)
    m2 <- sum(x == 2, na.rm = T)
    MAF <- min(m0,m1,m2)/sum(m0,m1,m2)
    MAF 
}


# lmo2
maf.fun3 <- function(x) { 
    myTable <- table(x)
    myTable <- myTable[names(myTable) %in% c("0", "1", "2")]

    min(myTable) / sum(myTable)
}


# sumedh
maf.fun4 <- function(x) {
    x1 <- tabulate(x + 1)
    x1 <- x1[x1!=0]
    x2 <- min(x1)/sum(x1)
    return(x2)
}


# eipi10 1
maf.fun5 <- function(x) {
    min(table(x))/sum(!is.na(x))
}


# eipi10 2
maf.fun6 <- function(vec) {
    min(sapply(na.omit(unique(vec)), function(j) sum(vec==j, na.rm=TRUE)))/sum(!is.na(vec))

}


# summarise each
wheatSingh_each  <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun1), -g1)
lmo1_each        <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun2), -g1)
lmo2_each        <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun3), -g1)
sumedh_each      <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun4), -g1)
eipi10_each      <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun5), -g1)
eipi10_each2     <- function(x) summarise_each(x, funs(maf.fun6), -g1)

microbenchmark(wheatSingh_each(dat), lmo1_each(dat), lmo2_each(dat),
               sumedh_each(dat), eipi10_each(dat), eipi10_each2(dat), unit = "ms")

Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 wheatSingh_each(dat) 1.260625 1.292623 1.385346 1.332168 1.414579 3.071865   100
       lmo1_each(dat) 1.258813 1.288095 1.387961 1.362054 1.430579 2.224808   100
       lmo2_each(dat) 1.782865 1.826939 1.962498 1.909652 2.009874 2.580416   100
     sumedh_each(dat) 1.270888 1.298057 1.431485 1.353300 1.416994 3.170276   100
     eipi10_each(dat) 1.700756 1.752377 1.896515 1.845957 1.921728 3.758326   100
    eipi10_each2(dat) 1.425448 1.482200 1.606445 1.555556 1.628910 3.496904   100

# sapply
wheatSingh_sapply <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun1)
lmo1_sapply       <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun2)
lmo2_sapply       <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun3)
sumedh_sapply     <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun4)
eipi10_sapply     <- function(x) sapply(x[, names(dat) != "g1"], maf.fun5)
eipi10_sapply2    <- function(x) sapply(x[, names(dat) != "g1"], maf.fun6)


microbenchmark(wheatSingh_sapply(dat[,-1]), lmo1_sapply(dat[,-1]), 
               lmo2_sapply(dat[,-1]), sumedh_sapply(dat[,-1]),
               eipi10_sapply(dat), eipi10_sapply2(dat), unit = "ms")

Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
 wheatSingh_sapply(dat[, -1]) 0.061583 0.0664130 0.07586755 0.0760730 0.0802995 0.114712   100
       lmo1_sapply(dat[, -1]) 0.054942 0.0597720 0.06603859 0.0639975 0.0700350 0.095393   100
       lmo2_sapply(dat[, -1]) 0.482394 0.5062425 0.52361843 0.5216380 0.5337130 0.607370   100
     sumedh_sapply(dat[, -1]) 0.063395 0.0694320 0.07805922 0.0754695 0.0812045 0.118336   100
           eipi10_sapply(dat) 0.420812 0.4431510 0.46422176 0.4603580 0.4787725 0.636954   100
          eipi10_sapply2(dat) 0.171464 0.1880680 0.20320984 0.1965200 0.2155380 0.329646   100



# data.table
wheatSingh_dt       <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun1)),.SDcols=cols])
lmo1_dt             <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun2)),.SDcols=cols])
lmo2_dt             <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun3)),.SDcols=cols])
sumedh_dt           <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun4)),.SDcols=cols])
eipi10_dt           <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun5)),.SDcols=cols])
eipi10_dt2          <- function(x) t(x[,.(ans=lapply(.SD, maf.fun6)),.SDcols=cols])



microbenchmark(wheatSingh_dt(dat1), lmo1_dt(dat1), lmo2_dt(dat1), sumedh_dt(dat1), 
               eipi10_dt(dat1), eipi10_dt2(dat1), unit = "ms") 



Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 wheatSingh_dt(dat1) 0.737780 0.7700795 0.8260051 0.8050970 0.8467555 1.307717   100
       lmo1_dt(dat1) 0.717856 0.7773255 0.8248158 0.8093235 0.8401145 1.397071   100
       lmo2_dt(dat1) 1.232248 1.2971515 1.3635452 1.3454505 1.4046180 2.021950   100
     sumedh_dt(dat1) 0.737176 0.7743060 0.8260775 0.8096255 0.8527940 1.364469   100
     eipi10_dt(dat1) 1.159195 1.2156455 1.3718648 1.2548890 1.3385075 4.757527   100
    eipi10_dt2(dat1) 0.869397 0.9095455 0.9691232 0.9512035 1.0082580 1.246738   100
```

**Note:** My solution (`maf.fun4` using `tabulate`) will work only when the values in the columns are integers

Results on the larger dataframe provided by @eipi10:

```
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(g1=1:536, replicate(1000, sample(c(1:100,NA), 536, replace=TRUE)))

sumedh_sapply     <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun4)
eipi10_sapply2     <- function(x) sapply(x, maf.fun6)

identical(sumedh_sapply(dat[,-1]), eipi10_sapply2(dat[,-1]))
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(sumedh_sapply(dat[,-1]), eipi10_sapply2(dat[,-1]), unit = "s")

Unit: seconds
                      expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  sumedh_sapply(dat[, -1]) 0.01308923 0.01393871 0.01615033 0.01714913 0.01766564 0.02056302   100  a 
 eipi10_sapply2(dat[, -1]) 0.40788421 0.42277774 0.44252427 0.42845991 0.43098025 0.56735431   100   b
```